# How to avoid duplicates when performing JOINS

Tags: mysql

I am creating an XML Feed using PHP and MySQL, it has been majoritively successful but a real issue I'm facing is that the items im passing into the feed have a unique ID which is related to some images in another table.

The XML nodes are generated by a query and a loop. The problem is each time I loop, if there is more than one picture all the information from the query is output again but with the second image URL.

So I get...

```
<ID>1</ID>
<URL>URL1</URL>
<ID>1</ID>
<URL>URL2</URL>
```

As you can probably tell any other fields that are included are also duplicated as long as there is more than one image URL because in my database it looks like this.

```
ID URL
1  1
1  2
1  3
```

Essentially the URLs are linked via the ID.

So if I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.id
```

I will get everything from table 1 duplicated as long as there is more than one image URL.

Is there a way to get everything from the first table and then get the imgurl's from the second table and list them in under the ID

Like this.

```
ID (other fields too)
img
img
img
```

Instead of

```
ID image (other fields)
ID image (other fields duplicated due to send url)
```

So in summary if I were to do SELECT * I'd get say name, surname, DOB but if i then JOIN the imgurl part id get...

```
name
surname
DOB
URL 1

name
surname
DOB
URL 2
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you want.  But a typical solution is to use aggregation and `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE2.URL)
FROM TABLE1 JOIN
     TABLE2.parent_id = TABLE1.id 
GROUP BY TABLE1.id;
```

This creates a comma delimited list of `url` from `table2`, for each record in `table1`.

Comment: I would like all the details on a person and then a list of URLs under that :)

Comment: That is not how SQL result sets work.  For instance, a column can have only one type.  Presumably, DOB is a date, but other columns are strings or numbers.  SQL result sets are tables, with well-defined columns and rows.